# CouchDB View with Multiple Parameters

Tags: view, couchdb

I have a database that has an id column and a ts column.  I need to be able to pass in the id and a start time and end time to retrieve all the values during the specified period.  Can I do this with a view, or do I need the view to return all of the values that match the id?  My concern is that I will be returning and parsing a lot more data than I really care about.  Here is the format of my DB from my current view, which simply returns everything that matches the id...

```
{"id":"62db2aa3472dce80b1f2193fc21d52fd","key":"A-Meter-KW","value":{"_id":"62db2aa3472dce80b1f2193fc21d52fd","_rev":"1-6aadd58f4f5dabacf6f4f638396246d0","id":"A-Meter-KW","ts":1437969600000,"tz":"New_York","val":"191kW"}},
{"id":"62db2aa3472dce80b1f2193fc21d5100","key":"A-Meter-KW","value":{"_id":"62db2aa3472dce80b1f2193fc21d5100","_rev":"1-71155153c0f03c49b02850bee5535e22","id":"A-Meter-KW","ts":1437968700000,"tz":"New_York","val":"190kW"}},
{"id":"62db2aa3472dce80b1f2193fc21d45d7","key":"A-Meter-KW","value":{"_id":"62db2aa3472dce80b1f2193fc21d45d7","_rev":"1-661511616958d45fdff3307600d2a9ed","id":"A-Meter-KW","ts":1437967800000,"tz":"New_York","val":"189kW"}},
{"id":"62db2aa3472dce80b1f2193fc21d3c23","key":"A-Meter-KW","value":{"_id":"62db2aa3472dce80b1f2193fc21d3c23","_rev":"1-4e97cfc6cb97ddc65f04efd9043b3abd","id":"A-Meter-KW","ts":1437966900000,"tz":"New_York","val":"188kW"}},
{"id":"62db2aa3472dce80b1f2193fc21d2e35","key":"A-Meter-KW","value":{"_id":"62db2aa3472dce80b1f2193fc21d2e35","_rev":"1-120298e95c9d2b4b9cdf438836b6c0c0","id":"A-Meter-KW","ts":1437966000000,"tz":"New_York","val":"187kW"}},
{"id":"62db2aa3472dce80b1f2193fc21d22b0","key":"A-Meter-KW","value":{"_id":"62db2aa3472dce80b1f2193fc21d22b0","_rev":"1-61e55d02bd8f0c601274b904f46c9f34","id":"A-Meter-KW","ts":1437965100000,"tz":"New_York","val":"186kW"}},
{"id":"62db2aa3472dce80b1f2193fc21d1ce2","key":"A-Meter-KW","value":{"_id":"62db2aa3472dce80b1f2193fc21d1ce2","_rev":"1-b4fe80563c70a40981e293af9c6a87b3","id":"A-Meter-KW","ts":1437964200000,"tz":"New_York","val":"185kW"}},
{"id":"62db2aa3472dce80b1f2193fc21d1ccc","key":"A-Meter-KW","value":{"_id":"62db2aa3472dce80b1f2193fc21d1ccc","_rev":"1-bdf1881c4270e68e7a7ed90a1d945228","id":"A-Meter-KW","ts":1437963300000,"tz":"New_York","val":"184kW"}},
{"id":"62db2aa3472dce80b1f2193fc21d1303","key":"A-Meter-KW","value":{"_id":"62db2aa3472dce80b1f2193fc21d1303","_rev":"1-404d5934fc882aa36e6d355d9a3485ae","id":"A-Meter-KW","ts":1437962400000,"tz":"New_York","val":"183kW"}},
{"id":"62db2aa3472dce80b1f2193fc21d0941","key":"A-Meter-KW","value":{"_id":"62db2aa3472dce80b1f2193fc21d0941","_rev":"1-64288d1c98e9b93aa6c546acb1e02078","id":"A-Meter-KW","ts":1437961500000,"tz":"New_York","val":"182kW"}}
...
```

... my current query is `http://localhost:5984/hist/_design/hist/_view/byId?key=%22A-Meter-KW%22&descending=true`.  I'd like to passing a start and end time as well, something like `http://localhost:5984/hist/_design/hist/_view/byId?key=%22A-Meter-KW%22&descending=true&start=1437963300000&end=1437966000000` but cannot figure out how to do this.

Answer (score 2):

EDITED: 
In order for Couch to match your query all the data (eg:A-Meter-KW and date) must be in the *key*, emitted by the view. So I think you might do something like:

**emit([key,year,month,day],doc._id)**

Then you can use the parameters *startkey* and *endkey* to filter the results properly.

Reference: http://guide.couchdb.org/draft/views.html#many

Side consideration: I would not use an "id" property inside my documents, because it could get easily confused with the "_id" (compulsory) one.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! While this may answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion, is this edit appropriate @IKavanagh?

Comment: Looks like it might work, so I gave an up-vote.  I was not however, able to find a solution in the time I had slotted and therefore moved my historical data into a sqlite db.  All my document based data is still running in CouchDB, but it does not appear to be a very good solution for time-series, historical data.  Therefore, I can not verify that this solution would solve my problem.  It was a while ago, but I seem to remember trying something similar and having issues with recursive views, or something like that.